# Too many indices error in image segmentation

Tags: image, numpy, indices, segment

I'm trying to decipher how to troubleshoot why I have an error in my code.

Basically, I have a JPG image and I need to segment it through using thresholds on the three RGB channels.

This is my code:

```
img = cv2.imread('sample.jpg')
img = np.asarray(img)
img = img[:,:,0:3]
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()

img_gray = rgb2gray(img)
img_gray = np.around(img_gray)
img_gray = img_gray.astype(int)
img_gray

histogram2, bins2 = np.histogram(img_gray, bins=range(255))
plt.bar(bins2[1:], histogram2)
plt.show()

img_select = np.where((img_gray[:,:,0]<150) & (img_gray[:,:,1]>70) & (img_gray[:,:,2]<90), 1, 0)
plt.imshow(img_select, cmap = 'gray')
plt.show()
```

The error is at the img_select part. I'm given this error:

"too many indices for array"

Can someone help me troubleshoot this?

Comment: `img_gray` is grayscale/single channel image. Use the original color image `img` to threshold the channels.

Comment: it worked! thank you!